# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I quit the app, relaunch it, I am getting an exception.

```
public void onCreate() {
-->here Parse.initialize(this, "adfsfasdfs",
            "asdfadfsdf");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    ParseInstallation.create(identity == null ? "No Identity Set"
            : identity);
```

Exception

```
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889):     at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:27)
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889):     at com.parse.ParsePlugins.access$200(ParsePlugins.java:11)
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889):     at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:141)
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889):     at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:178)
07-08 23:27:29.411: E/AndroidRuntime(4889):     at com.mcruiseon.caregiri.Registration.onCreate(Registration.java:98)
```

Manifest file

```
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Edit :

I wonder why Parse would throw an exception for this. Why not just `info` and move on. Its initialized, so big deal if I initialized it again.

**Solution**

I have given up on Parse. Dont like the Application way, just to irritating to maintain.

Comment: At what stage are you calling `Parse.initialize`, in your `onCreate`?

Comment: Yes, its in the onCreate

Comment: And is it the `onCreate` of a subclass of `Application` or do you call `Parse.initialize` somewhere else that could have been destroyed and calls it again?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`Parse.initialize()` should only be called ***once for an entire application***.

Calling it in an `Activity`'s `onCreate` function can cause it to be initialized more than once, as *an Activity can be created more than once during an app's lifecycle*.

Instead, create an **Application class** (and add an `android:name` attribute to your your application's manifest).

**Application: (Note not an Activity/Service/Reciever)**

```java
//Note that this is an android.app.Application class.
public class MyApplication extends android.app.Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    //This will only be called once in your app's entire lifecycle.
    Parse.initialize(this,
            getResources().getString(R.string.parse_application_id),
            getResources().getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
}
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```xml
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication">
        ....
        <activity>
            ....
        </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You did not tell me anything new ? You have just rephrased the question.

Comment: I don't see a named application in your manifest. Are you using `onCreate` in an **application** class or in an **Activity/Service/Receiver**? It won't work if you do it in anything but an application. Can you provide the code and context of your `onCreate` method? That might help to find the solution.

Comment: This is a working released application with 1000's of customers. I am adding Parse to it. Yes, its a Activity, yes I am initializing Parse in `oncreate`. And yes the manifest file has a `application`.

Comment: @Siddharth _"Yes, its a Activity, yes I am initializing Parse in oncreate."_ This is the part that is incorrect. If you look at my answer, I am calling `Parse.initialize()` in `public class Application extends android.app.Application` *NOT* `public class MyActivity extends Activity`

Comment: As @Khalos said. You cannot initialize (`Parse.initialize()`) Parse SDK in Activity or service because initialization can be performed only once in entire application process. Entry point for process is `Application` class which you can extend and add Parse initialization code as in @Khalos answear. So delete `Parse.initialize` from Activity onCreate and put in in Application onCreate.

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the point all along. I just cant believe it that Parse would do such a thing. Crazy. But I'll play along.

Answer (score 4):

NEVERMIND, I've fixed it. The problem was due to a syntax error. Thanks to all for solution.

This is weird as I've followed what's given but now I'm not getting any push notifications at all? The only changes I've made:

1. add app class to the manifest &
2. initialize parse in the app class. I'm using v1.10.1 of the SDK...

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="full.package.name.UseParse" >
```

Application class

```
public class UseParse extends android.app.Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "id", "key");
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for initialization yourself and just handle the exception and the error will not crash the app just quietly throw the exception.

```
        try {
            Parse.initialize(this);
            parseinited = true;
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using a boolean *isParseInitialized* variable .Works on orientation change i.e. when activity is recreated in the same Application session . Code snippet :

```
   public class YourActivity extends Activity {
        private static boolean isParseInitialized = false;
        public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "your_application_id";
        public static final String CLIENT_KEY = "your_client_key";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_youractivity);


    if(isParseInitialized==false) {
        Parse.initialize(this, APPLICATION_ID, CLIENT_KEY);
        isParseInitialized = true;
    }

  ..........

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static  boolean  parseIsInit = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (!parseIsInit){
            Log.d("demo",""+parseIsInit );
        Parse.initialize(this, "PutHereYourKeys", "PutHereYourKeys");
            parseIsInit=true;
        }
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    }
}
```