# creating app using parse.com lib.when i close app n reopen it ,it says unfortunately stopped

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have created activities such as splash screen, login page, register page and homepage, but when I close my app and try to reopen, it shows *error unfortunately stopped*.

Below is my splash screen activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Splash extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

        Parse.initialize(this, "app. id.(i can't show this privacy purpose :))",
            "Clint key(same here for privecy i will not show) ");

        Thread timer=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }finally {
                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    if (currentUser != null) {
                        // do stuff with the user
                        Intent taketohome=new Intent(Splash.this,HomepageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(taketohome);
                    } else {
                        // show the signup or login screen
                        Intent taketologinpage=new Intent(Splash.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(taketologinpage);
                    }
                }
            }

        };timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the logcat error?

Comment: This is the error sir @Dr.aNdRO Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context)`
            at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:58)
            at com.nintysixkmdev.marathiduniya.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:21)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is happening because you are doing Parse.intailize in onCreate method of activity. Instead you can make an application class and intialize Parse there. Hope it explains well

[Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300277/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-parseplugins-is-already-initialized/31307378#31307378?newreg=40f8fa9a990c42e2b6935707b667fd32)