# Parse push notification exception on click

Tags: android, exception, android-studio, parse-platform

Push notifications work great, when i send one it reaches the device.
When i click it it raises an exception.

this is my manifest refering to parse

```
  <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver
        android:name="org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.Receiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="org.cade.codigos" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

i extenden reciever class like i read in some post but still raises exception

```
public class Receiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("Push", "Clicked");
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

}

```
    10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime: Process: org.cade.codigos, PID: 8074
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.cade.codigos/org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:39)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:153)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:191)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.cade.codigos.ui.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:234)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-28 12:50:27.178 8074-8074/org.cade.codigos E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
10-28 12:50:28.923 8074-8074/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 8074 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post the code from ParsePushBroadcastReceiver, according to the logs Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized

Comment: where can ifind that?

Comment: Ok I belive you are using the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver (https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html), if you are, you should only do Parse.initialize() on your application

Comment: i have this on onCreate method,
Parse.initialize(this, "i6pkNI6ts626RdruO4b5KUT3ys2mwcmuA2jPpl6o", "O2kM8WtgzCZa8255a0ay8EIbpX96r6qMUxTb56fQ");
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

when the user clicks the notification , it is redirected to mainActivity right? you think this eception is because it is executed again?

Comment: Maybe this can help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31307378/706833