# ParsePlugins is already initialized error

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse for push notification i am getting following error

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized 
    at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:39) 
    at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:153) 
    at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:358) 
    at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:344) 
    at notifications.ParseUtils.registerParse(ParseUtils.java:30) 
    at com.techieweb.solutions.pickeronline.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:24) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309) 
    at android.app.ActivityTh read.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is ParseUtils class

```
 public class ParseUtils {

private static String TAG = ParseUtils.class.getSimpleName();

public static void verifyParseConfiguration(Context context) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID) || TextUtils.isEmpty(AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please configure your Parse Application ID and Client Key in AppConfig.java", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ((Activity) context).finish();
    }
}

public static void registerParse(Context context) {
    // initializing parse library
    Parse.initialize(context, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Successfully subscribed to Parse!");
        }
    });
}

public static void subscribeWithEmail(String email) {
    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

    installation.put("email", email);

    installation.saveInBackground();

    Log.e(TAG, "Subscribed with email: " + email);
}
 }
```

I have used this for reference http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

This is MyApplication

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application {

private static MyApplication mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;

    Parse.initialize(mInstance, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
     //register with parse
    ParseUtils.registerParse(this);

}


public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31300277/caused-by-java-lang-illegalstateexception-parseplugins-is-already-initialized

Comment: @sasikumar I refered it still getting error

Comment: You have to call `Parse.initialize()` in `onCreate` method of your `Application` class

Comment: @bigdestroyer I have called Parse.initialize() in onCreate method of MyApplication

Comment: Then, please update your code in the question.

Comment: @kishorejethava I have edited question please check

Comment: @bigdestroyer I have edited question please check

Comment: `ParseUtils.registerParse(this)` is calling again `Parse.initialize()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove below initialization from `oncCreate()`

```
 Parse.initialize(mInstance, AppConfig.PARSE_APPLICATION_ID, AppConfig.PARSE_CLIENT_KEY);
```

because you have already initialized inside

```
ParseUtils.registerParse(this);
```